# Which low level tasks can be accomplished on the JVM, but not expressed in java?

Tags: java, bytecode

Which useful (for performance or otherwise) constructions are valid bytecode, but not expressable in Java?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You can throw any object, not just exception.
2. You can overload on return type.
3. You can throw any exception without declaring it in throws.

Comment: You can only throw instances of `Throwable`, just like in Java source code. Any attempt to throw something else will already get rejected by the verifier.

Answer (score 3):

JVM bytecode is a [stack-oriented programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-oriented_programming_language), so most of the stack management instructions don't make sense in Java, e.g. `dup`, `swap`, etc. Arbitrary `goto`, of course, is also not expressible in Java.

Something like [JSR 292](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=292) proposes support for dynamically typed languages, which I don't think Java is planning to become.

I think something needs to be addressed here, though: your question seems to be at least partially motivated by the issue of performance. In practice, bytecodes are JIT-compiled to assembly. Whether or not there's a super magical bytecode instruction is really quite moot.

Comment: Can everything be reasonably left up to the JIT? Perhaps something like guaranteeing stack allocation?

Answer (score 2):

I have read that the bytecode method signatures support multiple dispatch on *return types*, whereas Java only allows for methods of the same name to dispatch on *parameter types*.

Comment: By that same token, you can probably fetch fields with the same name but different types as well.

Answer (score 1):

The opposite is also true sometimes.

For example, Java's visibility of inner classes cannot be represented in bytecode. The JVM only knows package-protected, protected, public and private visibility. So the Java compiler has to use a hack: It generates synthetic wrapper methods (which are package-visible) to expose the private fields and methods of inner classes to the outer class.

Comment: Visibility of inner classes is represented in bytecode using the INNERCLASS/OUTERCLASS attributes.